# How do I query a Django ForeignKey model field by choices' readable names?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Here is my class:

```
class UserProfile(TimeStampedModel):
    # some fields

class UserCohort(TimeStampedModel):
    CHOICE1, CHOICE2, CHOICE3 = range(3)

    COHORT_TYPES = (
        (CHOICE1, 'Readable 1'),
        (CHOICE2, 'Readable 2'),
        (CHOICE3, 'Readable 3'))

    user_profile = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='cohorts')    
    cohort = models.IntegerField(choices=COHORT_TYPES)
```

I want to make a filter query by readable name, not by integer. If I use `my_values = UserProfile.objects.filter(cohorts__cohort='Readable 1')` it doesn't work, but it works if I replace `'Readable 1'` with its corresponding integer `0`.

Is there a way to make the query via the readable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to use the `Readable 1` value because that is not what is saved in the database. However you can use the constant `CHOICE1` that you defined.

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(cohorts__cohort=UserCohort.CHOICE1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving `"Readable 1"` from the user then you're doing it wrong. Use the field values as the `value`s for the input elements. Or better yet, use a `ModelForm` that will handle everything for you.